# Problem on lines of table

Tags: tables

I wanted to create table but the following problem occurred:

[image: Problem on Table]

The problem is that the lines are not long enough.

Code:

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Gross errors found using plausible value check for ambient temperature in Nodes [25-28-29-31-32] }
    \label{tab:gr}
\centering
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{22}{c}}
\toprule
\bfseries Type & \multicolumn{22}{c}{\bfseries Node name} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-23}
& 25 & 28 & 29 & 31 & 32                 \\
\midrule
\bfseries A
& 20276 & 20302 & 20267 & 20263 & 20257    \\
\bfseries B
& 1376 & 1321 & 83 & 1329 & 1502             \\
\bfseries C
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0                           \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{23}{l}{A: Total number of observations}\\
\multicolumn{23}{l}{B: Number of faults}
\multicolumn{23}{l}{C: Number of faults in 2007-09-29}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have 22 columns but do not use all of them? The way that `\multicolumn` works means that 'unused' columns can cause some odd output: my first guess would be that this may be the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine after fixing the errors and adjusting the number of columns.

- Six columns are used (probably the real world case has 23).
- `\cmidrule` adjusted to `2-6`.
- `\\` is missing after `\multicolumn{...}{l}{B: ...}`.
- Using `6` in the `\multicolum` of the legend.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \caption{Gross errors found using plausible value check for ambient temperature in Nodes [25-28-29-31-32]}
  \label{tab:gr}
  \footnotesize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{5}{c}}
    \toprule
    \bfseries Type & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Node name} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-6}
    & 25 & 28 & 29 & 31 & 32 \\
    \midrule
    \bfseries A
    & 20276 & 20302 & 20267 & 20263 & 20257 \\
    \bfseries B
    & 1376 & 1321 & 83 & 1329 & 1502 \\
    \bfseries C
    & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{A: Total number of observations}\\
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{B: Number of faults}\\
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{C: Number of faults in 2007-09-29}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Gross errors found using plausible value check for ambient temperature in Nodes [25-28-29-31-32] }
    \label{tab:gr}
            \centering
                \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
                    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{5}{c}}
                        \toprule
                        \bfseries Type & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Node name} \\
                        \cmidrule(l){3-5}
                        & 25 & 28 & 29 & 31 & 32                 \\
                        \midrule
                        \bfseries A
                        & 20276 & 20302 & 20267 & 20263 & 20257    \\
                        \bfseries B
                        & 1376 & 1321 & 83 & 1329 & 1502             \\
                        \bfseries C
                        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0                           \\
                    \bottomrule
                \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{23}{l}{A: Total number of observations}\\
        \multicolumn{23}{l}{B: Number of faults}
    \multicolumn{23}{l}{C: Number of faults in 2007-09-29}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Welcome! Most people don't indent their codes, but I think this is an overindentation example). If you inden't you code you should do it by a reason, in this case, I see a lot of unnecessary indents.